# Infinite loop when adding 1 character to a list

Tags: c, list

I am writting a program which adds a character to a list. The problem is that when I have my original list of 5 nodes and I try to add another, everything works, but than when I try to add another one the stampa function becomes infinite.

I can not find the bug. Any help would be welcomed. Here is the code:

```
struct nodo {
    char c;
    struct nodo *next;
};
typedef struct nodo *lista;

void mc_coda(lista *l, char el);

void stampa(lista nodo01);

int main() {
    int test[5] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1};
    lista nodo01 = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    lista nodo02 = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    lista nodo03 = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    lista nodo04 = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    lista nodo05 = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));

    (*nodo01).next = nodo02;
    (*nodo02).next = nodo03;
    (*nodo03).next = nodo04;
    (*nodo04).next = nodo05;
    (*nodo05).next = NULL;

    (*nodo01).c = 'a';
    (*nodo02).c = 'b';
    (*nodo03).c = 'c';
    (*nodo04).c = 'd';
    (*nodo05).c = 'e';

    mc_coda(&nodo01, 'e');
    mc_coda(&nodo01,
            'f'); // If this line is removed everything workd fine, if this line
                  // if added that it         prints infinite f

    stampa(nodo01);

    return 0;
}

void mc_coda(lista *l, char el) {
    if ((*l) == NULL) {
        struct nodo temp;
        temp.next = NULL;
        temp.c = el;
        (*l) = &temp;
    } else {
        while ((*l) != NULL) {
            l = &(*(*l)).next;
        }
        struct nodo temp;
        temp.next = NULL;
        temp.c = el;
        (*l) = &temp;
    }
}

void stampa(lista nodo01) {
    while (nodo01 != NULL) {
        printf("%c\n", (*nodo01).c);
        nodo01 = (*nodo01).next;
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glimpse, it's because your `temp` structures will be going out of scope once `mc_coda` returns as they'll be created on the stack (vs those on the heap, allocated with `malloc`).  When you later refer to them, it's _Undefined behaviour_.  As is often the case with _UB_, things seem fine for a while - your program behaves as expected - but this is good fortune, not a reliable outcome; try the same thing more than once and it all falls apart.  EDIT: this is what @snek_case has said in their answer.

Comment: Two other points: 1. I'm afraid I only speak English, so I don't know what `mc_coda` means, but I'm guessing something like "add node"; perhaps you could clarify?  2. IMO, using `l` (lower-case letter 'ell') and `o` or `O` (letter 'oh') as variable names is a terrible idea, because they tend to look like numbers (and vice versa) and therein lie bugs.

Comment: Yes you are right, mc_coda is a function which should add the char in the end of the list. I should have clarified that

Comment: Hints: 1: don't hide pointer types behind typedefs, it only adds confusion. 2: instead of `(*foo).bar` you should write `foo->bar`, it's the same thing, but nobody uses the first form.

Comment: About point 2, yes I know about -> notation but I find that very confusing and not intuitive. The * notation i prefer much more.

Comment: @EntiolLiko, you should write the code you find clearest (as you have), but pretty much every other C programmer will do a double-take if they see `(*foo).bar` where `foo->bar` could be used.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `mc_coda` creates a local variable `temp`. Because `temp` is a local variable it will go out of scope when the function exits and then the space will be reused. Instead, you need to allocate space on the heap with `malloc`. See the below implementation of `mc_coda` for an example of how to do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodo {
    char c;
    struct nodo *next;
};

typedef struct nodo *lista;

void mc_coda(lista *l, char el);

void stampa(lista nodo01);

int main() {
    lista nodo01 = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    lista nodo02 = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    lista nodo03 = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    lista nodo04 = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    lista nodo05 = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));

    (*nodo01).next = nodo02;
    (*nodo02).next = nodo03;
    (*nodo03).next = nodo04;
    (*nodo04).next = nodo05;
    (*nodo05).next = NULL;

    (*nodo01).c = 'a';
    (*nodo02).c = 'b';
    (*nodo03).c = 'c';
    (*nodo04).c = 'd';
    (*nodo05).c = 'e';

    mc_coda(&nodo01, 'e');
    mc_coda(&nodo01, 'f');

    stampa(nodo01);

    return 0;
}

void mc_coda(lista *l, char el) {
    lista tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    tmp->next = NULL;
    tmp->c = el;
    if ((*l) == NULL) {
        (*l) = tmp;
    } else {
        while ((*l) != NULL) {
            l = &(*(*l)).next;
        }
        (*l) = tmp;
    }
}

void stampa(lista nodo01) {
    while (nodo01 != NULL) {
        printf("%c\n", (*nodo01).c);
        nodo01 = (*nodo01).next;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer to the immediate problem.  In practice, the OP could use the new `mc_coda` function in place of the separate `malloc`s and assignments at the start.

Comment: I wanted to keep the diff as minimal as possible for clarity.